# Sender's name is not taken into account by WildFly while sending mails

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, gmail, jakarta-mail, wildfly

Mail service configuration in standalone-full-ha.xml.

```xml
<mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default" from="admin@mydomain.com">
    <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"
                 ssl="true"
                 username="sender@gmail.com"
                 password="password"/>
</mail-session>
```

```xml
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
    <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Injecting the mail session through the service bound to the JNDI name `java:jboss/mail/Default` and sending mails using that mail session.

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/Default")
private Session mailSession; // javax.mail.Session

MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
Address[] to = new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("recipient@gmail.com")};

mimeMessage.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
mimeMessage.setSubject("Subject", "UTF-8");
mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
mimeMessage.setText("Message", "UTF-8", "html");
Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```

Now, the sender's name i.e `from="admin@mydomain.com"` as specified in the XML configuration above is expected to be sent as a sender but the server instead keeps on sending the user name as specified by `username="sender@gmail.com"` as a sender.

Doing like the following in Java code itself does not help either which works in Java SE environment.

```
Address from = new InternetAddress("admin@mydomain.com");
mimeMessage.setFrom(from);
```

What consequences the server dislikes.

<sub>Using WildFly 9.0.2 final.</sub>

---

**Update :**

The debug output on the server log.

```
06:27:24,562 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
06:27:24,562 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
06:27:24,562 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
06:27:25,296 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:25,296 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465
06:27:25,296 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 
06:27:25,296 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) EHLO om-f6b0ea3ad206
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [117.198.186.188]
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-SIZE 35882577
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-8BITMIME
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-PIPELINING
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250-CHUNKING
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250 SMTPUTF8
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
06:27:25,625 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
06:27:26,578 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
06:27:26,578 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
06:27:26,578 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) MAIL FROM:<sender@gmail.com>
06:27:26,875 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250 2.1.0 OK g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:26,875 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) RCPT TO:<recipient@gmail.com>
06:27:27,156 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250 2.1.5 OK g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:27,156 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
06:27:27,156 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP:   recipient@gmail.com
06:27:27,156 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DATA
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 354  Go ahead g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Date: Sat, 30 Jan 2016 06:27:24 +0530 (IST)
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) To: recipient@gmail.com
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Message-ID: <17076900.1.1454115444562@gmail.com>
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Subject: Subject
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) MIME-Version: 1.0
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) Message
06:27:27,515 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) .
06:27:28,437 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 250 2.0.0 OK 1454114106 g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:28,437 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
06:27:28,437 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) QUIT
06:27:28,718 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) 221 2.0.0 closing connection g26sm26113121pfg.35 - gsmtp
06:27:28,718 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-21 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-7949294)) DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.3
```

---

Sending a mail using a Java SE console application :

```
public class Mail {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        send("sender@gmail.com", "password", "recipient@gmail.com", "Subject", "Message", "Sender Name");
    }

    private static void send(String sender, String password, String recipient, String subject, String message, String senderName) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender, senderName, "UTF-8"));
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress(recipient)});
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        mimeMessage.setText(message, "UTF-8", "html");
        mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", sender, password);
        transport.sendMessage(mimeMessage, mimeMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

It can take any arbitrary name as the sender name as specified in the last parameter of the `send()` method above.

On opening the message sent, the sender is shown like `Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>` in the message body. In the former case, it is however shown like `sender@gmail.com`.

The debug output on the console terminal device :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP m87sm26277196pfi.47 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 465

EHLO om-f6b0ea3ad206
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [117.198.186.188]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<sender@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK m87sm26277196pfi.47 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<recipient@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK m87sm26277196pfi.47 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   recipient@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead m87sm26277196pfi.47 - gsmtp
Date: Sat, 30 Jan 2016 07:46:18 +0530 (IST)
From: Sender Name <sender@gmail.com>
To: recipient@gmail.com
Message-ID: <13329486.0.1454120181750@om-f6b0ea3ad206>
Subject: Subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Message
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1454118752 m87sm26277196pfi.47 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

The sender's password used is an application specific password obtained during "2-Step Verification" at `https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords`.

<sub>The difference in versions of the API is negligible / can safely be ignored in this case. I already attempted using older versions of the java-mail API. The former uses the version 1.5.3 and the latter uses the version 1.5.5.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gmail won't let you specify any arbitrary From address.  If you want to send as someone different than you logged in as, see [this Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

Comment: Sorry, it does not help. How does it work in Java SE environment then where it takes any arbitrary name? Under the "Accounts and Import " tab, option, "Send mail as: ", it shows `User Name <sender@gmail.com>`. Therefore, specifying `from="User Name &lt;sender@gmail.com&gt;"` in the XML configuration should work either way but it does not.

Comment: JavaMail takes any arbitrary name, most servers including Gmail do not.  Did you test your Java SE program against Gmail?  It may be that WildFly is doing something different that's part of the problem, but the general issue of sending from an arbitrary address remains.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show in the two cases?

Comment: You're definitely not calling the setFrom method in the WildFly case.  Setting "from" in the mail-session definition isn't going to do that.  It might provide a default if you call setFrom with no arguments.

Comment: Calling `MimeMessage#setFrom()` without arguments works which takes `from` from the XML configuration.